# Why is apache refusing requests to www.mydomain.org if mydomain.org is working fine?

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost

This is the setup I have working for mydomain.org:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
  ServerName mydomain.org
  ServerAlias *.mydomain.org
  DocumentRoot /var/www/
</VirtualHost>
```

If I request www.mydomain.org, apache throws a 403 with the following appended to the log:

> (13)Permission denied: /root/.htaccess pcfg_openfile: unable to check htaccess file, ensure it is readable

I've tried changing ServerName to www.mydomain.org, and changing ServerAlias to www.mydomain.org as well with no luck.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried actually checking whether the .htaccess file is readable (or why Apache wants to read it)? ServerName should be mydomain.org, ServerAlias www.mydomain.org.

Answer (score 0):

You ou can not put an star (*) in ServerAlias. You should put the name you want.
In your case, `ServerAlias www.mydomain.org` should be written.
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#serveralias

Edit : I found something http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/vhosts/name-based.html for your problem. I think there is another problem in your configuration, like an other virtual host, with an other root directory.

Comment: Yes, there was another problem.  I am on Ubuntu; I have been editing /etc/apache2/sites-available/default and I had also edited /etc/apache2/httpd.conf earlier adding another VirtualHost stanza.  Which is more correct to use out of the two files if I'm looking to set up several virtual hosts matching different subdomains?

Comment: Create a file in /etc/apache2/sites-available for each virtualhost you have. Don't forget to activate it with `a2ensite file` Then each virtualhost is easy to find and to manage.
Check http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/412

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are trying to do wildcard DNS, in this case you CAN use an asterix.

Here's a good link I found: http://ma.tt/2003/10/wildcard-dns-and-sub-domains/

Also, siding with Emthigious, check your .htaccess file permissions.